# Semantic similarity on a large dataset

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cosine-distance

I'm going through [this](https://newscatcherapi.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-text-similarity-with-python) guide on semantic similarity and use the code there as is.

I'm applying it to a dataset where each row is typically a paragraph (3-4 sentences, over 100 words). Currently, I have over 100k observations, but this number is likely to grow to 500k.

I want to measure semantic similarity between all rows.

When I test BoW and TFIDF on around 20-30k sample, I don't get any performance issues (even without cleaning, stopwords, etc.).

When I try Word2Vec/Universal Sentence Encoder, however, it takes couple of hours to finish even on 3-4k rows sample .

I also get completely different results, but that's beyond the point.

Is there a way to improve the performance for Word2Vec/Universal Sentence Encoder, especially the latter. (As far as I understand, in Word2Vec, words "good" and "bad" may [cancel each other out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932912), which is not good for my speach-like data.)

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to profile the code to empirically find the slowest parts. A quick visual scan of the code you referenced relieved inefficiencies.

For example, there are several list comprehensions:

```py
labels = [headline[:20] for headline in headlines]

docs = [nlp(headline) for headline in headlines]
```

One straightforward way to speed up the code is converting those into generator expressions.

Additionally, there are nested for-loops:

```py
similarity = []
for i in range(len(docs)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(docs)):
        row.append(docs[i].similarity(docs[j]))
similarity.append(row)
```

You may not need to do a doc-by-doc comparison.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I need the doc-to-doc comparison (1 vs all). From what I gathered, the bottleneck is measuring the similarity (on a sample of 5-10k paragraphs). For example, using a simple example from https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html my code crashes at `util.cos_sim(embeddings, embeddings)` (CUDA of out memory). I think the only way is to feed embeddings in batches, but not quite sure how yet.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- I understand that you calculate similarity between every pair of rows/documents, right? If so, the bottleneck is due to the quadratic processing of all the pairs First, you should compare only $(d_1,d_2)$ and not $(d_2,d_1)$ (using indexes: if $i<j$), this saves 50% time. I also assume that the goal is to capture pairs/groups of strongly similar documents. If yes, a method would be to first apply the BoW/TFIDF method (simpler and faster), then to apply the embeddings method only to the pairs which obtain at least some similarity threshold with the first method.
- A completely different approach: apply [topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) (LDA, or HDP, or other recent method) on the set of document. This would be likely faster. It might also reveal a different kind of semantic similarity betweem documents.

Comment: Thanks, this helps! I understand your point about trying to reduce the dataset to those that show promise, but I think even then it will be a very large dataset. Following your suggestion, I tried `mylist = []
for i in range(len(sentence_embeddings) - 1):
  for j in range(i+1, len(sentence_embeddings)):
    if i < j: 
      measure=util.cos_sim(sentence_embeddings[i], sentence_embeddings[j])
      mylist.append({'index': [i, j], 'score': measure})
    else: 
      pass`, it's not efficient and I still get a `CUDA out of memory` error for 10000 sample. Could you suggest an improvement?

Comment: @narrativera dividing by 2 is useful but not enough for a quadratic explosion, the number of pairs increases too fast. What you could study is the number of pairs above a given threshold $t$ with the TFIDF method. If you plot $t$ as x and number of pairs as y, my guess is that you would find that (1) the number of pairs is very high when $t$ is low and very low when $t$ is high; (2) there's probably a sharp change between these two parts, and a point where $t$ is optimal: catching all/most of the similar pairs while not including too many.

Comment: thanks! Still, I have almost 500k paragraphs. Even if I select a _t_ that eliminates 99% of all observations, it leaves me with 5k rows (~12.5mn pairs). I'd still have a memory problem. I'm asked to use as many pairs as possible. I was thinking of running the code for 1000 pairs, saving the checkpoint, then exporting the results, cleaning the memory, and restarting the loop. But not quite sure how to code it and whether it's an optimal way.

Comment: Found this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44133/how-to-apply-similarity-algorithmor-comparision-of-over-one-million-vectors-wi and this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/69737/fastest-way-for-1-vs-all-lookup-on-embeddings 

They refer to FAISS, Dask and Gensim. Not familiar with any of them, will try to figure out.

Comment: @narrativera 500k*500k/2=125.10^9, it's a lot of comparisons. If you have access to a server or a lot of hardware resources why not, but honestly I would certainly use topic modelling for this: my guess is that it would work better than TFIDF, and possibly even as well or better than the embedding method. And the computing time would be reduced a lot.

Comment: yeah, I don't want to spend power needlessly. I'm not very familiar with topic modelling. Say I get topics for each paragraph. Will I be able to calculate cosine similarity or some other measure to compare these paragraphs. Since my paragraphs vary in size, it's likely that I'll get varying number of topics. Also, I assume that LDA would be the fastest way to get results?

Comment: @narrativera LDA would have to be applied to the whole corpus, I think that could be a disadvantage for your case. to compare between paragraphs, LDA and most other models can provide  a distribution over topics (e.g. topic 0 20%, topic 1 40%, etc.) for every doc/paragraph, so the standard way to measure how similar two docs they are is to compare their distributions. Yes, I think it would be much faster.